# How to confirm a sandbox paypal account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying paypal adaptative payments, I create 2 business accounts on paypal sandbox to make a chained payment here: 
`https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/merchant`

I set up a ficticious card number, now I have $20 MXN there, everything is ok, I just get the error:
`Account my-account@gmail.com isn't confirmed by PayPal`

I'm not receiving any message from paypal to verify account.

Comment: If you can provide either the email address or the merchant id for the test sandbox business account I can check to make sures its confirmed on my end and confirm it if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. so this is how PayPal sandbox works:-

1. You need to have a valid PayPal account to login to PayPal developer sandbox. If you don't have one, then you'd be asked to create a new account.
2. Once you login to sandbox, you can create several fictitious users - email addresses of these users will usually have _api1 suffixed to the email address - example foobar_api1@gmail.com

I believe, PayPal might be asking you to confirm the account created in step 1 - you might have created a new PayPal account to login to sandbox which might verification in pending state. Double check that and I think your issue will be resolved.